# AJAX / PHP not working on new WAMP server

Tags: php, ajax, wamp

We've moved a php page from one WAMP server to another and the chap who created it has left the business.  I know nothing about AJAX, so am struggling!

I've scoured the code on both the old server and new, and it's exactly the same but for some reason the AJAX on the new server isn't working correctly, whereas on the old server it's fine.

What it's supposed to do is show a list of people from our database, allow users to update those records and then show the new, updated record without refreshing the page.

On the old server, it works a treat but on the new server it doesn't load the new data through.  It's probably something ridiculously basic, but I'm scratching my head (mainly as I know nothing about the technology!)

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: I would compare PHP error_reporting variable at first. Probably there is some notice in the ajax reply and that's causing problems.

Comment: If you do a call to a hardcoded url, you might be requesting the AJAX from the old location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the error console we were seeing an error 500 from the server (which seemed odd and rather unspecific...!)

Having had someone we know take a look at the code, it seems that on the old server, it seemed quite happy using mssql_close($con); but on the new server it didn't and so simply replacing it with sqlsrv_close($con) then meant the page the ajax was calling could complete and then returned the results as expected!

Always the little things...!

Answer (score 1):

Have you made sure the script that you are requesting with AJAX is actually there? You have said you've uploaded the script but is the path exactly the same? Different environments may have different paths to the same script.

Also how are you making the AJAX request? Are you using (for example) the jQuery library that might exist on one environment but not the other? Are they both using the same version of jQuery?

Use the Javascript console to see what errors you're getting and go from there. Chrome and Firefox have the best ones by default.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Error_Console

Before any of this though I would make sure the original script is working and returning the right results.

Answer (score 0):

First check:

Look into the Javascript code and find where the actual URL is constructed.
It will look like:
xmlhttp.open("GET","yourAjaxPage.php",true);
but the xmlhttp can have a different name.

Now, simply alert this URL, or document.write(), or anything that gives you the url.

Put this URL into the browser-url and see the response.

In case you are using a session, make sure you use the same browser (TAB for example) where you expect the result.

Now you will see the response from the server to the request you just made. This should get you going finding the problem.